# Is there any way use the values in a cell to query a SQL table and see if the value exists in the table?

Tags: sql, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet containing all of my company's Vendor Codes. When a new code is added to this spreadsheet, we then add it to a configuration table within our database which allows us to accept that vendor. Right now I'm going through my Excel Spreadsheet and reviewing each section of code to find out if it exists in the SQL Table.

Is there any way use the values in a cell to query my VendorConfig table and see if it exists?

Spreadsheet Columns: VendorID, VendorCode, Config

Comment: did you try to use VBscript in a macro ?

Comment: Yes, I have done similar with Oracle.  It's been a while, but I had a .vbs program that opened the spreadsheet and connected to the database then looped through all rows in the sheet, using a cell value to look up the value in the database, then wrote it to a new column at the end of the row in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "get external data" command to bring a value into a cell to check against. Alternatively, here is a link to a web post that has a cool answer to this problem (NOTE: I haven't actually tried this code but, from a quick glance, it looks right): [Add formula to excel to validate data](http://www.engineers-excel.com/Tips/SQLookup/SQLookup.htm)